# Get value from query string from slice url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get query string value by name from slice url. I tried many ways to get value but it is not working.

For eg. :- http://example.com/xyz/12-13/pqr/55-66

I want to get xyz and pqr value which is 12-13 and 55-66 respectively.

How can i get ?

```
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

console.log(getParameterByName("xyz"));
```

It is return null....

How can i get please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `console.log(getParameterByName("xyz","http://example.com/xyz/12-13/pqr/55-66"));` and not `console.log(getParameterByName("color"));`?

Comment: sorry. I update my code ...still it will return null

Comment: Is url pattern always the same?

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').reduce((r, e, i, a) => { if (i % 2 === 0) r[e] = a[i + 1]; return r;  }, {}); => {xyz: "12-13", pqr: "55-66"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var splittedPath = new URL('http://example.com/xyz/12-13/pqr/55-66').pathname.split('/');
console.log(splittedPath[splittedPath.indexOf('xyz') + 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? I did it just in my head though...

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        parts= url.split('/'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (parts[i] === name) {
            return parts[i + 1];
        }
    }
}

console.log(getParameterByName("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
var url = "http://example.com/xyz/12-13/pqr/55-66"
function getParameterByName(name) {
  var toArray = url.split("/");
  for(arr in toArray){

    if(toArray[arr]==name && arr < toArray.length-1){
        return toArray[parseInt(arr)+1];
        }
  }
  return "No value Found";
}

console.log(getParameterByName("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below function with simply passing your param name.

```
function GetParamValuesFromQueryString(param) {
    var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0].toLowerCase() == param.toLowerCase()) {
            return urlparam[1];
        }
    }
}


console.log(getParameterByName("pqr"));
console.log(getParameterByName("xyz"));
```